# save image to subfolder of /library/Application Support/bundleID_name/... iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsurl, nsfilemanager, file-uri

The following code works without error or exception - but still, it does not do what it should ! I wanted to save an image into the iOS library/Application Support folder. More precisely, the image should be placed into a /library/Application Support/bundleID_name/subfolder/ (and the subfolder being called "location1").

If I check the functionality with the iOS-Simulator, I can see the creation of the subfolder (i.e. .../library/Application Support/bundleID_name/location1/). Also the function "saveImage" works without exception. But there is no image being saved !!!! (i.e.the image-file is missing and the folder remains empty) !!

What could be the mistake ??

Here is my code with the call of two functions (see code below):

```
UIImage *in_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"template009c.jpg"];

NSString *locDirectoryName = @"location1";
NSURL *LocationDirectory = [self appendLocationToApplicationDirectory:locDirectoryName];

[self saveImage:in_image :@"image1" :LocationDirectory];
```

With the corresponding function-Nr1:

```
- (NSURL*)appendLocationToApplicationDirectory:(NSString*)locationDirName
{
    NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSFileManager*fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL*    dirPath = nil;

    // Find the application support directory in the home directory.
    NSArray* appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    if ([appSupportDir count] > 0) {
        // Append the bundle ID and the location-Foldername to the URL for the Application Support directory
        dirPath = [[[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID] URLByAppendingPathComponent:locationDirName];

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        // This method call works in OS X 10.7 and later only.
        NSError*    theError = nil;
        if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&theError]) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"%@", theError.localizedDescription);
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            // Mark the directory as excluded from iCloud backups
            if (![dirPath setResourceValue:@YES
                            forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                             error:&theError]) {
                NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from iCloud backup %@", [dirPath lastPathComponent], theError.localizedDescription);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Location Directory excluded from iClud backups");
            }
        }
    }
    return dirPath;
}
```

And function Nr2:

```
//saving an image
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image :(NSString*)imageName :(NSURL*)pathName {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *LocationDirectory = [pathName absoluteString];
    NSString *fullPath = [LocationDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];

    /***** THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT SEEM TO DO WHAT IT IS SUPPOSED TO *******/
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

    /**** I also tried without the FileManager, but same problem - no file written...  ***/
    // [imageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:NO];
    NSLog(@"image saved");
}
```

By the way, getting the "fullPath" with the XCode-Debugger, I get:

```
"fullPath   NSPathStore2 *  @"file:/Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/2BCC3345-9M55F-4580-A1E7-6694E33456777/Library/Application%20Support/bundleID_name/image1.png" 0x09d50950
```

Doesn't that also seem correct ?? But why is [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; not performing ???

Comment: You don't check for errors, so that's why you don't see any.

Comment: Good point, but where would you start checking for errors and how ?

Comment: @Droppy: I tried:     if(![fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating File at Path %@", fullPath);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"image saved");
    } ...And yes, now an error occurrs. But the question still remains why or do you have an idea ? Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Yup; much better.  And do you get an error?

Comment: Yes I get an error :) But don't know why...:/

Comment: OK so now use the version of that method that writes back an `NSError` object and that will tell you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
"fullPath   NSPathStore2 *  @"file:/Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/2BCC3345-9M55F-4580-A1E7-6694E33456777/Library/Application%20Support/bundleID_name/image1.png" 0x09d50950
```

is not a valid path, it's a URL path but stored in a string. If you are going to use URL's then use ULRs rather than trying to convert to a string:

```
[imageData writeToURL:pathName atomically:YES];
```

(preferably naming the parameter as `pathURL`) and if you want to use paths then don't use a URL at any stage.

Also, where an API method returns an error or status flag, check it in the code as standard.

Comment: Great help! Thank you very much, Wain! I will stick with either one of the two (i.e. path or URL). By the way, by replacing one line of code, it would eventually have worked in the first place! (...the conversion from a NSURL to a NSString is the method "path" instead of "absoluteString". Check code-line: "NSString *LocationDirectory = [pathName path];" That way it worked for me! Thanks again for your help !!

Comment: By the way, the reason why I was using URL's in the first place was that it seems easier for me to exclude the created path and file from the iCloud-backup. (i.e. [dirPath setResourceValue:@YES
                            forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                             error:&theError]). I found this method somehow only for a URL, not for a path....

Comment: Again, thanks a lot Wain for your support ! It all makes sense now:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't save an image on a path you specify. You can save images on the gallery or in DocumentDirectory. This should be the code to save an image on the DocumentDirectory:

```
NSString *imgName=[@"imgname.png"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:imgName forKey:@"imageName"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];
UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is my image from camera
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```